# Macro takes lot of time to retrieve data

Tags: excel, vba, performance, index-match

I am creating a macro to preocess salary arrears. But it is getting more time to retrive deta.

There are many deta in my Deta sheet (60,0000 Rows with Deta) and i used index match function like below to det deta in to few variables. Then calculations depends on variable (My Code Attached here with).

```
OT = Evaluate("INDEX('" & ws2.Name & "'!G:G, MATCH(C4&""-""&A" & startRow + i & "-DAY(A" & startRow + i & ")+1,'" & ws2.Name & "'!C:C&""-""&'" & ws2.Name & "'!B:B, 0))")
```

I tried to find a better answer but not yet. I am looking forward to your kind guidance to resolve this issue (even by modifying my code).

Comment: My only suggestion: chop the data into subsets and deal with each separately. Otherwise vtc as lacks detail.

Comment: Seems like Powerquery would be a better approach but if you insist on using vba you should look into "dictionary" .

Comment: Another alternative - load the entire data into an Array (one line of code) and process that instead (in memory much faster than manipulating a worksheet). Having said that, Power Query gets my vote

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speeding up VBA Code to Run Faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763554/speeding-up-vba-code-to-run-faster)

Comment: Eny methord to get values to variables